# How to transfer the `perspectiveTransform` position back to the img_scene's position?

Tags: c++, opencv

Here is the source code:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography

The line I am interested in is this one:

`perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);`

And I look at the scene_corners, the coordinate is very strange, it is very small, I would like to convert it related to the `img_scene` object. What function I can do with it? Thanks.

Comment: post your H homography matrix it can be wrong.

Comment: I just use the sample code...Nothing special.

Comment: but images that you use can generate special H